# Returning result of class function in Python

Tags: python, class

I'm relatively new to OOP in Python (I have been using it mainly in conjunction with Tkinter), and there is one issue I have come across which is bugging me.

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1="Hello World"
        self.check()
    def check(self):
        if self.var1=="Hello World":
            return True

if test()==True:
    print("These are the same")
```

As an example, is there a way that I can, in plain English, 'return the value twice' so that the 'True' that is returned is considered the result of the class itself (not just the function), therefore executing the 'if' statement and printing "These are the same"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats input() here ?

Comment: @Gohn67 - You cannot return a value from a constructor (well, except for `None`, which is returned implicitly).

Comment: @iCodez Doh! Good point. I should have been paying more attention. Comment deleted. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are considered to have a truth value if (among a few other rules) their class defines a method called `__bool__`. So all you need to do is to rename your `check` method to `__bool__` and your example will work with a minor change: check `if test():` to ensure this is triggered. Note this doesnt return the value twice, but it checks the 'truthiness' of the object you just constructed - the same Python rule says that, for example, `if mylist:` checks if mylist has any elements.

For good measure, you might like to have that method return False when the check fails - it currently returns None. The best way to do this is to rewrite it slightly:

```
def __bool__(self):
    return self.var1 == "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you may be looking to do this:

```
if test().check():
    print("These are the same")
```

`test()` creates your instance of class `test`, and `.check()` returns either `True` or `False` from the method `check()`.

---

NOTE: It is common convention to name your classes using *TitleCase*, and it's best to explicitly subclass `object`. So:

```
class test():
```

Should be:

```
class Test(object):
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way to do this. You would have to set a variable, something like `self.checkTrue`, then check `test.checkTrue` to see if it was true. Example:

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1="Hello World"
        self.check()
    def check(self):
        if self.var1=="Hello World":
            self.checkTest = True
test = test()
if test.checkTest:
    print("These are the same")
input()
```

Another issue is you never made a new variable that object, fixed that also.

Answer (score 0):

When you call a class, it's a constructor, so it *always* returns an instance of that class. Still, you can give your class another method that returns whatever you like, and use that instead of a constructor.

```
class Foo:
    @classmethod
    def create(cls, arg):
        self = cls()
        return [self, arg]
foo = Foo.create("bar")
```